# IK for this IkParameterizationType not implemented yet

Tags: ros, moveit, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have followed the instructions for generating an IKFast plugin located [here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/IKFast), and have successfully generated an IKFast package using the instructions. Unfortunately the link to the method of running the plugin in Rviz ([link](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Rviz_Plugin/Quick_Start)) does not have any content so I am once again left guessing.

When I run RViz using:
`roslaunch hyd_sys_complete_sldasm_moveit_config demo.launch`

I get the following errors repeatedly:
`[ERROR] [1409802774.965529932]: IK for this IkParameterizationType not implemented yet.`

This does not make sense to me, as when I examine the source code the control type (`Translation3d`) was specifically given as an argument for generating the IKFast package, yet it claims there is no implementation for it.

Here's the offending generated code. I am using `Translation3D` as my solver yet it is not covered in the `solve` function given below.

```
int IKFastKinematicsPlugin::solve(KDL::Frame &pose_frame, const std::vector<double> &vfree, IkSolutionList<IkReal> &solutions) const
{
  // IKFast56/61
  solutions.Clear();

  double trans[3];
  trans[0] = pose_frame.p[0];//-.18;
  trans[1] = pose_frame.p[1];
  trans[2] = pose_frame.p[2];

  KDL::Rotation mult;
  KDL::Vector direction;

  switch (GetIkType())
  {
    case IKP_Transform6D:
      // For **Transform6D**, eerot is 9 values for the 3x3 rotation matrix.

      mult = pose_frame.M;

      double vals[9];
      vals[0] = mult(0,0);
      vals[1] = mult(0,1);
      vals[2] = mult(0,2);
      vals[3] = mult(1,0);
      vals[4] = mult(1,1);
      vals[5] = mult(1,2);
      vals[6] = mult(2,0);
      vals[7] = mult(2,1);
      vals[8] = mult(2,2);

      // IKFast56/61
      ComputeIk(trans, vals, vfree.size() > 0 ? &vfree[0] : NULL, solutions);
      return solutions.GetNumSolutions();

    case IKP_Direction3D:
    case IKP_Ray4D:
    case IKP_TranslationDirection5D:
      // For **Direction3D**, **Ray4D**, and **TranslationDirection5D**, the first 3 values represent the target direction.

      direction = pose_frame.M * KDL::Vector(0, 0, 1);
      ComputeIk(trans, direction.data, vfree.size() > 0 ? &vfree[0] : NULL, solutions);
      return solutions.GetNumSolutions();

    case IKP_TranslationXAxisAngle4D:
    case IKP_TranslationYAxisAngle4D:
    case IKP_TranslationZAxisAngle4D:
      // For **TranslationXAxisAngle4D**, **TranslationYAxisAngle4D**, and **TranslationZAxisAngle4D**, the first value represents the angle.
      ROS_ERROR_NAMED("ikfast", "IK for this IkParameterizationType not implemented yet.");
      return 0;

    case IKP_TranslationLocalGlobal6D:
      // For **TranslationLocalGlobal6D**, the diagonal elements ([0],[4],[8]) are the local translation inside the end effector coordinate system.
      ROS_ERROR_NAMED("ikfast", "IK for this IkParameterizationType not implemented yet.");
      return 0;

    case IKP_Rotation3D:
    case IKP_Translation3D:
    case IKP_Lookat3D:
    case IKP_TranslationXY2D:
    case IKP_TranslationXYOrientation3D:
    case IKP_TranslationXAxisAngleZNorm4D:
    case IKP_TranslationYAxisAngleXNorm4D:
    case IKP_TranslationZAxisAngleYNorm4D:
      ROS_ERROR_NAMED("ikfast", "IK for this IkParameterizationType not implemented yet.");
      return 0;

    default:
      ROS_ERROR_NAMED("ikfast", "Unknown IkParameterizationType! Was the solver generated with an incompatible version of Openrave?");
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Is there something in the `kinematics.yaml` file for the RViz plugin I need to change?

I know that the standard kinematic solvers do not work properly for my arm as it only has three degrees of freedom, but unfortunately IKFast has proven much more trouble than it is worth.

Is there a solution to this?

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191884/ik-for-this-ikparameterizationtype-not-implemented-yet./) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What this means is: You have correctly created a Translation3D solver using IKFast. But the plugin, which wraps your solver, doesn't know how to handle Translation3D yet, because I haven't implemented it yet; I have never used Translation3D, so I couldn't test it.

What the switch statement you quoted does is that it calls `ComputeIk()` from the generated solver; the `ComputeIk()` type signature is always the same, but the meaning of the arguments differs depending on the IkParameterizationType. For Translation3D there is only the translation, which is already stored in the variable `trans`, so you can probably leave the second argument (the direction/rotation/...) as NULL, like this:

```
    case IKP_Translation3D:
      ComputeIk(trans, NULL, vfree.size() > 0 ? &vfree[0] : NULL, solutions);
      return solutions.GetNumSolutions();
```

Please let me know if it works, so I can update the `moveit_ikfast` package!

P.S.: I recommend asking MoveIt-related questions on the moveit-users mailing list, since most developers are reading that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-04**:
Thank you. It did cross my mind to put in the `ComputeIK` call in those case statements, but I was not sure of the calling convention for it. Can I confirm that if this works properly I will be able to drag the arm around in Cartesian coordinates in 3D in RViz?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-09-04**:
Yes, correct.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-04**:
I can confirm that Martin's answer is correct. Thank you very much. I just need to tidy up the behaviour a little when the end effector reaches the limits of its workspace (it tends to jump around) but other than that this is the answer.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-09-05**:
I just noticed that somebody already added Translation3D support to moveit_ikfast (in commit f8c8cc2e76) in February, so this is already fixed in the source (only not released as .deb yet).